# If else condition to replace value in php

Tags: php, if-statement

I had a php script to run the if else to replace the value based on condition:

```
//$mobile = '23456701';
$mobile = '01234567';

$zero_lead = "/^01/";
$country_code = "44";


$phone = preg_replace($zero_lead, $country_code, $mobile);

if (strpos($phone, '/^0/') !== true) {
   
   $accountNumber = $mobile;
   
}
else
{
    $accountNumber = '';
}

$post_data = array(
                'phone' => $phone,
                'accountNumber' => $accountNumber,
            );

echo json_encode($post_data);
```

return: `{"phone":"44234567","accountNumber":"01234567"}`

my expected return if `$mobile = '01234567';` will return `{"phone":"44234567","accountNumber":""}`

and `$mobile = '23456701';`will return `{"phone":"23456701","accountNumber":"23456701"}`

any one have suggestion?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is not JS, so you can't use RegExp expressions in primitive functions such as strpos.

```
$mobile = '01234567';
$account = $mobile;
$country_code = '44';

if (substr($mobile, 0, 2) === '01')
{
    $account = '';
    $mobile = $country_code . substr($mobile, 2);
}

echo json_encode
([
    'phone' => $mobile,
    'accountNumber' => $account
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `$count` parameter to [`preg_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace) to see if a replacement was made (i.e. the `$mobile` value started with `01`), and then use that to set the value of `$accountNumber`:

```
$phone = preg_replace($zero_lead, $country_code, $mobile, -1, $count);
$accountNumber = $count ? '' : $mobile;
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/dn6Zh)

Comment: Tried your code also works, bith of yours code work properly.